# Align lwc made with Grid - Lightning Design System

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, design, slds-grid

[image]

[image]

Can anyone guide me on how to align columns and rows?

```
<template>

<lightning-card  title="Opening hours">

    <!-- Monday -->   

    <div class="slds-grid slds-no-flex">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small"> 
                <lightning-badge label="Monday   :"></lightning-badge>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="time"></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="time"></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="toggle" message-toggle-active="Open" message-toggle-inactive="Close" checked></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br></br>

    <!-- Tuesday -->   

    <div class="slds-grid slds-no-flex">
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-badge label="Tuesday:"></lightning-badge>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="time"></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="time"></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-size_1-of-16">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="toggle" message-toggle-active="Open" message-toggle-inactive="Close" checked></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using incorrect classes for column sizing. The [slds grid](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) is a 12 column grid, not 16. You need to divide the viewport into 4 division. It can be 3,3,3,3 or 2,4,4,2 or anything else.

Based on that you can fix the slds col classes.

Also in your `lightning:input`, if you do not want to show the label, use the `variant="label-hidden"`

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-no-flex">
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small"> 
                <lightning-badge label="Monday   :"></lightning-badge>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="time"></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="time"></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_2-of-12">
            <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">
                <lightning-input type="toggle" message-toggle-active="Open" message-toggle-inactive="Close" checked></lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can also utilize lightning:layout for this.

Comment: Thanks @manjit5190 ! Your answer was very useful.

Still cant align the heights (horizontally) and remove the borders, any idea?

Comment: The borders are there because you are using slds box class. You will need to make sure that apply a class only of you know what it does.